# Scope of add_host

Tags: ansible

This is the playbook I'm trying to run.

```
---
# ansible/site.yml

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: local
  sudo: no
  roles:
    - ec2

- hosts: ec2hosts
  gather_facts: yes
  user: ubuntu
  roles:
    - supervisor
```

Here is part of the ec2 role.

```
--- 
# ansible/roles/ec2/main.yml

# Provision EC2 instances
# ...
  register: ec2

- name: Add EC2 instances to host groups
  add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=ec2hosts
  with_items: ec2.instances
```

The first part works fine, and the hosts seem to be added correctly, but once it gets to the next play, (installing supervisor on the newly created `ec2hosts`), it gives me a `skipping: no hosts matched`.

So why does my main playbook not recognize the host group that was created during the first play?

*Edit:*

Hosts file. Do I need to declare a host group here for it to be globally accessible? I've tried removing the `[ec2hosts]` line as well as running without specifying this as the inventory file.

```
# inventory/hosts
[local]
localhost

[ec2hosts]
```

Running it:

```
ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventory/hosts ansible/site.yml -vvv
```

Relevant output:

```
...

TASK [ec2 : Add EC2 instances to host groups] ***************************

PLAY *******************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: What version of ansible are you running?

Comment: Development branch, so >2

Comment: What you are doing should work.  Can you post how you are running from the command line?  Does your inventory have an existing ec2hosts group?  Can you post the output running with -vvvv?

Comment: Doesn't look like your loop is running for the add_hosts module.  Can you verify ec2.instances contains a list of instances?  When I run something similar, and hosts actually get added, the facts returned by the add_hosts module shows which hosts were added.

Comment: You're right, something with `with_items: ec2.instances` is not working because nothing is happening at that stage. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Is it possible you need to add 'wait: yes' to the task that actually provisions the new machines? I've had issues where failing to wait causes IPs, public or private, to not get captured, causing subsequent plays to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your loop for the add_host modules isn't running.  Check and make sure your ec2.instances variable is properly populated